# (Unity3d) Chartboost and Admob can't Compatible

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services, chartboost

In my game, there is already a Admob plugin setup, and I want to set up Chartboost plugin too. When I setup the Chartboost plugin, I **can't make the apk package**.

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>   D:\Android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.1\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay
>   -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "D:/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_
>   --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:com.unity3d.player:com.unity.purchasing:com.android.vending.billing:com.google.unity.ads:com.unity.purchasing.googleplay:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.clearcut:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:com.unity3d.ads:com.pushok.test
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.1.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\common\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GoogleAIDL\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\GooglePlay\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-base-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.0\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-clearcut-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-drive-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-games-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-gass-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-nearby-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-10.0.1\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-24.0.0\res"
>   -S "E:\unityWork\MySlots\SlotsGame\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityAds\res"

And seems to be the file `AndroidManifest.xml` made this error.

Comment: please post how you have added Chartboost plugin

Comment: @Nilabja just import Chartboost package and click 'Chartboost' button on the menu to set.

Comment: Clicking that button ("Setup Android SDK") will install Google Play Services as well as other libraries that Chartboost deems necessary. Can you double check your project as well as your Android Manifest to make sure you don't have any duplicate libraries within your project?

Comment: @C.amiry Thanks, I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a backup, so I use git to find what changed in my project.

I find when I set up the Chartboost (click 'Setup Android SDK' button), there is added a file `play-services-basement-9.0.0.aar`, And I already have `play-services-basement-10.0.0.aar`.So I delete the 9.0.0 file.

Now I can make the apk package!

Answer (score 0):

Your error [`CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.`](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/760989/failed-to-re-package-resources-2.html) might occurs when you have an `AndroidManifest.xml` file (Probably under Plugins/Android or a plugin in a subfolder of this folder) that tries to access a resource by name (google_play_services_version), but this value is never defined anywhere. Usually, this value is added via some method such as adding it to the `AndroidManifest.xml` or to an `xml` under `res/values`.

Another workaround is:

> To fix this error, you have to copy the `version.xml` file from
>
> ```
> android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/res/values/
> ```
>
> into `Assets/Plugins/Android/res/values/` of your Unity project's folder.

Additional resource:

- [Unity 5 Android Build - Failed to re-package resources](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1074000/unity-5-android-build-failed-to-re-package-resourc.html)
- [Failed to re-package resources : aapt.exe package](https://forum.unity.com/threads/failed-to-re-package-resources-aapt-exe-package.411575/)

Comment: Hey, but I can't find the folder (android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services\libproject )